# Xcode 6.1 cannot drag connection to a property from XIB

Tags: uilabel, viewcontroller, xcode6.1

I've just started with Xcode and I'm having a certain difficulty. I've placed a label on the canvas, declared property in viewcontroller.m, and now I'm trying to draw a connection into it, but it doesn't seem to exist. What am I doing wrong ?

I've added a screenshot - the property is not on the list for some reason, as you can see.

Using Xcode 6.1!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKDmy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your view in your xib file and then click on File's Owner here:[image]

With File's Owner selected, then open the identity inspector and make sure the class of File's Owner is ViewController like so:

[image]

Once you set the class of File's Owner to ViewController, you should see the UILabel property appear in the Connections Inspector for File's Owner.

Also, just for reference, the File's Owner for a view in a Xib file typically refers to the view controller (the view controller owns its view).

Comment: Thanks for responding ! :) I'm a little confused. I am not using Storyboard, but the xib directly. I found the custom class but it seems like everything is empty. I've attached a screenshot again. http://i.imgur.com/9K6tsTe.png